# I can't save image name to xml file

Tags: php, xml

I have file name data.xml and I want to save image name there. My image correct save in the folder name upload but I want to save the name of my image in xml file but these isn't possible.

Do you have any decision of what to do;

```
 <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
    <?php
    $out="";
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $file="data.xml";
        $entryNode='entry';
        $doc= new DOMDocument('1.0');
        $doc->preserveWhiteSpace=false;
        $doc->load($file);
        $doc->formatOutput=true;

        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0){
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
        }
        else{
            echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";

            if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])){
                echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
            }
            else{
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
                if ($_FILES['file']['name']!=""){
                    $picture=$_FILES ["file"]["name"];
                }
            }
        }
        $root=$doc->documentElement;
        $entry=$doc->createElement($entryNode);
        $entry=$root->appendChild($entry);

        foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
            $node=$doc->createElement($key,$value);
            $entry->appendChild($node);
        }
        $doc->save($file);  
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: do you get an error message?

Comment: No. It display in html Stored in: upload/blahblah.jpg but the files name doesn't displayed to my xml file

Comment: do you want to save the uploaded file or data.xml?

Comment: no. to upload file and save the file's name to data.xml.  I can save the file but the file's name doesn't saved to data.xml

Comment: check the last foreach $_POST. $entry->appendChild($node); is going no where. if you need to see the content of a variable use var_dump($variable); for example

Comment: I don' t understand what you mean

Comment: Try to output the xml with `var_dump($doc->saveXml())`. If the ouputs the correct xml you might have a permissions porlbem, try to use an absolute filename and increase the error level.